# UPS not importing data from AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory, user-profile-service

I have setup User Profile Service Application.

User Profile Service is running.
User Profile Synchronization Service is running.

I did full profile synchronization. The synchronization started and after few minutes it stopped but I don't see any profile imported by it. What could be the reason?

The service account that synchronizes has REPLICATE DIRECTORY permission because when I first went to create synchronization connection, and entered that user/password, it showed me all OUs from AD. Or may be just because I was able to see all OUs from AD doesn't mean this service account has REPLICATE DIRECTORY permission!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the account has the following permissions

-Replicating Directory Changes

-Replicating Directory Changes All

-Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set

-Replication synchronization

http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/user-profiles-synchronization-job-not-synchronizing/

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY permission you need is **"Replicating Directory Permissions"**. That is ALL. You do not need all the other permissions mentioned above. This is pure misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the logs generated by the MIIS client to determine where the issue is. Run the MIISClient.exe in the SharePoint Application folder under Synchronization Service\UIShell. After that recheck the whole configuration against Spence's article here: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx Even though it states it's for 2010 it is still valid for 2013.

Usually the problem always comes back to permissions incorrectly applied.